# How google adsense's ad placement works?

Tags: javascript

How google adsense determines where to place ads? What's the logic behind placing ads on the dynamic DOM elements? The header and footer DOM element can be identified. How about ads in between content or posts.

Comment: Would be shocked if this is not very well documented and an easy topic to search

Answer (score 1):

Google Adsense doesn't determine where to display the ads, you have to insert an adsense code snippet that positions the ad where you want it to display in your page/code. For ads within an article, like inside of a wordpress loop, you have to use javascript (a wp plugin etc.) to inject the ad code in the DOM where you want it to show up. Usually you can decide that the ad will display X paragraphs down in the article.

Comment: So, for example if i need three ads at top, bottom, sidebar I should place 3 ad units?

Comment: @AmreshVs Yes correct. This article is thorough and recent: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-google-adsense-to-your-wordpress-site/